Variants of weak optimization problems for convex sets
In their famous book, Grotschel Lovasz and Schrijver (1993) present several algorithmic problems on convex sets. Each of these problems has a strong variant and a weak variant. In particular, the strong optimization problem (SOPT) for a convex set $K$ is:

Given a vector $c$ in $R^n$, either :

find a vector $y$ in $K$ such that $c^T y \geq  c^T x$ for all $x$ in $K$, or -
assert that $K$ is empty.


The weak optimization problem (WOPT) is:

Given a vector $c$ in $Q^n$ and a rational $\epsilon >0$, either -

find a vector y in $S(K,\epsilon)$ such that $c^T y + \epsilon \geq c^T x$ for all $x$ in $S(K,-\epsilon)$, or -
assert that $S(K,-\epsilon)$ is empty.


Here, $S(K,\epsilon)$ is the ball of radius $\epsilon$ around $K$, defined as $$\{x \in R^n : |x-y| \leq     \epsilon \text{ for some } y \in K\},$$ and $S(K,-\epsilon)$ is the interior $\epsilon$-ball of $K$, defined as $$\{x \in K : |x-y| \leq \epsilon \text{ implies } y\in K\}.$$
Comparing WOPT to SOPT shows that WOPT is weaker in three respects:

$y$ is allowed to be in $S(K,\epsilon)$, which is only approximately in $K$;
$y$ should satisfy $c^T y+\epsilon \geq c^T x$, which is only approximately maximum;
$y$ is allowed to be (approximately)-maximum only with respect to $S(K,-\epsilon)$, which is smaller than $K$.

This means that, formally, there are 8 different variants: each combination of these 3 relaxations leads to a potentially different variant. For example, we could define a variant in which only the optimization is relaxed, that is, given a vector $c$ in $Q^n$ and a rational $\epsilon >0$, either -


find a vector y in $K$ such that $c^T y + \epsilon \geq c^T x$ for all $x$ in $S(K)$, or -
assert that $K$ is empty.


MY QUESTION: which of these 8 variants is "interesting" in the sense that it is not equivalent to either SOPT and WOPT?
Put differently: for which of these variants is there (a) a reduction from SOPT, showing that it is as hard as the strongest variant, or (b) a reduction to WOPT, showing that it is as easy as the weakest variant?
EDIT: (c) which of these variants are equivalent in the sense that there is a polynomial-time two-directional reduction between them?

Please proof-read your question - there appear to be some Mathjax errors.
